# Reactivity of carbonyl derivatives with a nucleophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, nucleophilicity

As observed, the reactivity of carbonyl derivatives with a nucleophile goes like:

Acid halide > acid anhydride > acid > amide > ketone > aldehyde. So is nucleophile a code word to nucleophilic substitution (nucleophilic acyl substitution in this place)?

My professor gave the explanation by saying that look out of $\delta^+$ charge on the carbonyl carbon of each compound, the one that has the most is the one which reacts most with a nucleophile.

And, if we consider that, then the order according to professor is:

Acid halide > aldehyde > ketone > acid anhydride

Is there anyway this order may be correct?

I'm a student btw, so I got no knowledge about the lab and practical stuff.

Comment: You need to be more specific as to the nucleophile.

Comment: No it didn't ...I also asked if my professors order could be somehow correct. And I know the reason behind the order but what I'm asking is reactivity with a nucleophile a code word to nucleophilic substitution?

Comment: It's from one of the questions where they say that check reactivity with a nucleophile...so the nucleophile remains the same (any) with carbonyl derivatives changing.

Comment: The reactivity order in you list is different from that in Mithoron's reference. Also, you have amide>ketone>aldehyde. I'd think the reverse is true. You said "as observed", what reaction was studied in the observation?